# Get rid off css jitter on animation

Tags: css, css-animations

could anybody help me out how to get rid of the css jitter?

HTML here:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS here:

```
.carousel-inner {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.item {
  background-image: url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1462834026679-7c03bf571a67?dpr=1&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1500&h=989&q=80&cs=tinysrgb&crop=);
  background-position: right bottom;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  animation: wdszoom0 5s linear 0s infinite alternate;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
@-webkit-keyframes wdszoom0 { 100% { background-size: 120% 120%; }}
```

Fiddle here:
https://jsfiddle.net/kybernaut/zkzod6wh/2/

I have read this and that, but didn't helped me out:

- [Jitter on chrome css animations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19736847/jitter-on-chrome-css-animations)
- [Chrome CSS 3 Transition Not Smooth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754561/chrome-css-3-transition-not-smooth)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to animate the `transform` property as it is much smoother. In [this](https://jsfiddle.net/zkzod6wh/3/) example I changed the `background-size` with `transform: scale`.

```
@-webkit-keyframes wdszoom0 { 100% { transform: scale(1.1) }}
```

You can read more about smooth animations in this [article](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/high-performance-animations/).

Comment: thanks a lot, I haven't thought about doing it as a transform ;)

Comment: but what if I want to apply it only to the background of the item not to the whole content?

Comment: Then you might want to think of having a wrapper which you can animate, and keep the content still... :)

Comment: If the wrapper is `.item` with the animation and the content is within `.item > .content` doesn't work..